# How to serialize XML with nullable fields

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, nullable

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Program
{
    internal class Program
    {
        internal static void Main()
        {
            string xml =
            @"<row>
                <AI></AI>
            </row>
            ";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(row));
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                row book = (row)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class row
    {
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public int? AI;
    }
}
```

It just does not work:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (3, 15).'

If I feed xml to XDocument and try to serialize this document instead it does not work either.

StackOverflow compels me to write more letters about the issue, I don't know what else to say, I feel very sad and overwhelmed.

Comment: Well I was really hoping for something more direct

Comment: The problem is that `<AI></AI>` is not null, it's an empty string, which is not the same thing

Comment: @NickFarsi - Unfortunately there is nothing more direct.  Microsoft serializers are less customizable than say Json.NET.  Only other option I can imagine is to preprocess the XML with an xslt transform or via LINQ to XML.